# What MS-Works version works on Windows 2008 Server with remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

... if any ?

Recently switching from Windows 2003 Server to 2008 my MS-Works 7 version does not install at all. I'm running now in a VM with XP but prefer to have it installed.

Comment: Some info regarding the actual errors encountered would be useful...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need to ask why. Why would you ever want to run Works 7 on a server? Or why use Works at all?

Comment: He may have documents he needs to open, and doesn't have a compatible file reader. It's possible.

Comment: Yes users was working a long time with PC manufacture included software (Dell delivered PC's with MS-Works).

Comment: If you have a server OS, I'm assuming you have office as well. You can open those documents in Office and Save As them to .doc or .docx and it will convert them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing Works 7 using Server '08's compatibility mode?

Try running the MS-Work 7's setup file using XP compatibility - it *should* get through.

[image]

Comment: yes i have tried this, no luck

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to install it in Windows 2008. Your VM solution is the best bet scenario.

Comment: Why won't it install?